# Blur classes in UIKit missing

Tags: objective-c, uikit, ios7, blur, xcode5

Anybody tried blur effects in iOS 7 presented at the **WWDC 2013 - session 226: Implementing Engaging UI on iOS**?

I tried to use the code snippets mentioned at time 15:00:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NULL, 0);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect];
.
.
.
```

etc...BUT the code won't run, because it calls methods and classes that are not even in the API.

Plus I downloaded the sample project - Running with a Snap. That project doesn't even compile because the classes imported are simply not in the there. Example project...seriously...

Anybody knows if there is **ANY** way how to do the blurs in iOS 7 without using 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: can you give sample code..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013#

Sample project for getting the ideas - can't get it to compile :(

Comment: Oops, sorry..looks like it won't send proper link - it's the project mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They haven't implemented the api for it yet.  A neat temporary solution has been found in the mean time that involves stealing the background layer of UIToolbar.

[You can find the solution here bundled up in a nice class](https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur)

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!